# Thermal pad for TFP401APZP IC

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, analog, integrated-circuit

I am using an 100 pin TFP401APZP IC ,in the data sheet it says that there is a provision for thermal pad also the IC has exposed metal at the bottom area.

Why do we need thermal pads ? is it ok if we don't use thermal pads ?

Comment: You need thermal pads because of heat. Sometimes it's okay not to use it, but 99% of the time you will need/want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it ok if we don't use thermal pads ?

Sometimes yes, sometimes no - it depends on the specific IC. In some cases (see below) there can also be *electrical* considerations. As always, read and understand your device's datasheet and application notes.

For the TFP401APZP the answer is in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tfp401a.pdf) on page 25:

> > **Soldering the back side of the TFP401/401A to the application board is not required thermally**, because the device power dissipation is well within the package capability when not soldered.
> >
> > **Soldering the back side of the device to the PCB ground plane is recommended for electrical considerations**. Because the die pad is electrically connected to the chip substrate and hence to chip ground, connection of the PowerPAD back side to a PCB ground plane helps to improve EMI, ground bounce, and power-supply noise performance.

Answer (score 2):

Thermal pads are used to help dissipate the heat generated by the IC die during operation. If the chip overheats it can lead to permanent damage of the device. The thermal pad itself gives you a sort of heat sink which helps dissipate the heat, but sometimes that won't be enough. Sometimes it is required that you also create a thermal pad on your PCB (an exposed section of copper) that the thermal pad of your chip can be soldered to, and then your PCB would act as a heat sink itself. It's not uncommon in high-power ICs for there to be a patch of copper directly under the chip (which solders to the thermal pad of the IC), which connects to an even larger pad on the other side of the PCB using via stitching (a large array of small vias connecting the copper pads together). This greatly increases the surface area of the copper and allows more heat to be dissipated more easily.

Depending on how hard you plan to drive your IC, you may not need a thermal pad. However, I would generally recommend using one anyway just to be on the safe side. Follow the manufacturer's recommended footprint for the device to make sure your PCB's thermal pad is large enough.